# Changing how Text To Speech pronounces an app name

Tags: android, accessibility

We are producing an app that is for market in Ireland. Ireland is an English speaking country but our app name includes a name that is in Irish. Because of this when the voice assistant is turned on the pronunciation of our app's name is completely wrong and additionally "OK Google" will not pick up our app.

In an iOS app there is the option to set the CFBundleSpokenName to change how the accessibility screen reader pronounces an apps name. Is there an equivalent to this in Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This option is not available on Android platform yet, but you can create a [Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=190923&template=841312). Select in Template section Feature Request and describe your demand.